# Sound design not sufficently highlighted

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

Just to say that from my opinion:

Sound design and synth making is not sufficiently highlighted here.

I see many posts about gears, configurations,and software problems.

Does anyone see a way of getting more people with real "sound design" questions to come and create a dynamic around it? By sound design I mean precise tips for specific sound creation or reproduction, mixing techniques and more Max MSP coding for sound design. Am I completely dreaming or do you feel a bit the same?

Tell me what you think about it?

Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens on many sites in beta phase - asking questions in a particular area to get specialists to join in is an obvious first step, but where does one get the questions from in a specialist area?

The chicken or the egg...?

Solutions we have seen work on other sites include:

- self seeding questions
- inviting specialists directly
- posting links to questions on social media
- suggesting a "topic for the week"

Comment: Thx for the answer

Answer (score 5):

Man, you should have been around 2 1/2 years ago when this site was originally Social Sound Design! That was all we did -- discuss sound creation, sound recording, editing and mixing techniques, etc. It was fab. (In fact, almost all of those threads are still archived here, I'm sure you can find them with a search.)

Since the SSD/SE merge, most of those original contributors have either stopped frequenting this site or abandoned it altogether, for the exact reason you are pointing out: There was little to no discussion of sound design going on, a whole lot of talk about gear and newbie questions, and the sound design questions that were posted were so over-moderated that people just stopped trying.

That said, all is not lost! I'm still here (the last of the original SSD moderators actively participating) and am very interesting in seeing the spirit of that forum return here.

So ask away! I'll be listening for sure.

Comment: I'm planning on frequenting this forum regularly this year so I guess I'll try to do my best to ask real sound design questions (mostly for bass music). Plus bass music synth is pretty technic and might attract youths. But I'm really happy to hear what you've just said :)

Comment: I'm not sure how much I'll be able to add to your conversation as I don't really think of "bass music" as sound design. In my world, sound design is what we create for films, television, theatre, etc., ie. a way to help the director convey story through the use of sound.

Comment: Well music is sound design too, many effects are similar to ones in movies... and sometimes it also tells a story?! no ?!

Comment: Of course, music may be the ultimate storytelling device as there are no visuals to reference! Totally agree with you. My point is that I approach sound design from a filmic perspective rather than a pure musical view. I look forward to seeing how we influence each other -

Comment: Cool :) Happy to hear that.